# query connection in excel with new data loaded

Tags: vba

The Query from MS Access Database11 is available and is refreshed when the a(refresh ODBC) results in a subscript out of range error. I'm not sure what to do. Thank you :).

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim sR As String
Dim sFile As String
Sheets("annovar").Activate
Range("A1").Select
sR = MsgBox("Clear the annovar sheet for new data?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2)
If sR = vbYes Then
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Sheets("annovar").UsedRange.Clear
    ChDrive "N:\Torrent\Setup\Clinical"
    ChDir "N:\Torrent\Setup\Clinical"
    On Error GoTo 0
    sFile = Application.GetOpenFilename _
        (FileFilter:="Text Files, *.txt", MultiSelect:=False)
    Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=sFile, Origin:=437, StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
        FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), _
        Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1), Array(9, 1), _
        Array(10, 1), Array(11, 1), Array(12, 1), Array(13, 1), Array(14, 1), Array(15, 1), Array( _
        16, 1), Array(17, 1), Array(18, 1), Array(19, 1), Array(20, 1), Array(21, 1), Array(22, 1), _
        Array(23, 1), Array(24, 1), Array(25, 1), Array(26, 1), Array(27, 1), Array(28, 1), Array( _
        29, 1), Array(30, 1), Array(31, 1), Array(32, 1), Array(33, 1), Array(34, 1), Array(35, 1), _
        Array(36, 1), Array(37, 1), Array(38, 1), Array(39, 1), Array(40, 1), Array(41, 1), Array( _
        42, 1), Array(43, 1), Array(44, 1), Array(45, 1), Array(46, 1), Array(47, 1), Array(48, 1), _
        Array(49, 1), Array(50, 1), Array(51, 1), Array(52, 1), Array(53, 1), Array(54, 1), Array( _
        55, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Copy
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("annovar").Range("A1").PasteSpecial
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Close False
    Sheets("annovar").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End If
'Refresh ODBC connection
ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Query from MS Access Database11").refresh
End Sub
```